# Convert Array of Objects into Array of Array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, angular, object

In my angular app, I get the values from service as an array of objects like below.

```
temp=  [
    {
        "a": "AAA",
        "b": "bbbb",
        "c": "CCCC",
        "d": "ddddd",
    },
    {
        "a": "lmn",
        "b": "opq",
        "c": "rst",
        "d": "uvw",
    }
 ]
```

I need to format this temp to array of array of strings:

```
newTemp = 
[
 ['AAA', 'bbbb', 'CCCC', 'ddddd'],
 ['lmn', 'opq', 'rst', 'uvw'],
];
```

Should we need to do a forloop on each object or is there any straight forward way.

Comment: Depends if has to work on IE too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.map`

```
let newArray = arr.map(a => Object.values(a))
```

If you cant use `Object.values`

```
let newArray = arr.map(a => Object.keys(a).map(k => a[k]))
```

Output

```
(2) [Array(4), Array(4)]
    0:(4) ["AAA", "bbbb", "CCCC", "ddddd"]
    1:(4) ["lmn", "opq", "rst", "uvw"]
```

Comment: I tried to use without Object.values, it says 'Cannot convert undefined or null to object'

Comment: one small simple change, is there a way that we add additonal elements to the new generated array. For example ['false', 1, "AAA", "bbbb", "CCCC", "ddddd"]  Basically 'false' and a numeric to display rownumber

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```js
temp=  [
    {
        "a": "AAA",
        "b": "bbbb",
        "c": "CCCC",
        "d": "ddddd",
    },
    {
        "a": "lmn",
        "b": "opq",
        "c": "rst",
        "d": "uvw",
    }
 ]
 
 var newTemp = [];
temp.forEach(function(obj){
    var arr = [];
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
      arr.push(obj[key]);
   })
   newTemp.push(arr);
});
console.log(newTemp);
```